# How to increase wifi sensitivity?

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless

Since I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (fresh, not upgrade), my wifi is much weaker than before and much weaker than under Windows XP. 
There is a noticeable difference in required sensitivity: It doesn't establish a connection unless I carry the notebook directly to the hotspot (so that the indicator shows 3 or 4 bars). However afterwards the connection breaks only when I move farther away (1-2 bars).
(Side note: I remember my 9.04 had stronger wifi than XP.)

My wireless interface is `wlan0` and with `sudo lspci -nn` I found that my network controller is:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
```

Should I report it as a bug?

Is there a configuration how I can improve it?

Comment: The operating system you use has nothing to do with your Wi-fi card's signal strength.

Comment: The operating systems I use(d) have different drivers to control the (same) wireless hardware. I am sure that the signal strength of the hotspot was not changed.

Comment: I tried `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` but I get `Error for wireless request "Set Power Management" (8B2C): SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.`

Is anyone able to give a really helpful idea?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still an issue in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: I do not believe you will get an answer but I made one that is full of things you can check. If I find more I will edit them in :)

Answer (score 3):

Do not trust the bars... 5 full bars might be lots of noise and just 2 bars might be without noise. [More about this here](https://superuser.com/questions/459938/meaning-of-line-bars-in-wifi-signal-strength-db-and-negative-values) (is about Windows but same physics apply for Ubuntu). There is a better method: `more /proc/net/wireless` shows quality of the link, signal strength and noise level.

Example:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ more /proc/net/wireless 
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   57.  -53.  -256        0      0      0     34   1185        0
```

[For each device, the following information is given](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Linux.Wireless.Extensions.html):

- Status : Its current state. This is a device dependent information.
- Quality - link : general quality of the reception.
- Quality - level : signal strength at the receiver.
- Quality - noise : silence level (no packet) at the receiver.
- Discarded - nwid : number of discarded packets due to invalid network id.
- Discarded - crypt : number of packet unable to decrypt.
- Discarded - misc : unused (for now).

A high value of Discarded - nwid packet might indicate a nwid configuration problem or an adjacent network. The Quality - level might help him to track shadow areas.
The basic difference between Quality - link and Quality - level is that the first indicate how good the reception is (for example the percentage of correctly received packets) and the second how strong the signal is. The Quality - level is some directly measurable data that is likely to have the same signification across devices.

Command `iwspy` (exampe `sudo iwspy wlan0`) can show command line results on your wireless but only if it supports [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) otherwise it will show "Interface doesn't support wireless statistic collection"

Now more related to the problem at hand ...

1. This https://superuser.com/questions/431523/improving-wifi-connections-in-linux states:

   - Use a program or iwlist to scan for other wireless networks and, if possible, set the frequency/channel of your router to be at least two channel numbers away from any neighboring networks
   - sens - sensitivity is very subjective and requires you to fiddle with it a lot
   - rts - setting this to auto helps
   - txpower - check your NIC to see what it's capable of, I've had good luck setting linksys/cisco NICs to 84mW
2. Also interesting: [Wireless Internet Connection so slow after upgrade to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73523/wireless-internet-connection-so-slow-after-upgrade-to-11-10)

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and post back next time I use wifi.