# wifi is not working after updating 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless

today I updated my ubuntu 11.10 via the update manager. Now, the wifi connection is not working. I see my wifi station and the network manager also connects to the station but I cannot ping any other machine as well as connect to any other machine.

I use dhcp and I have disabled ipv6. If I call ifconfig everything looks fine, I see If my address. I also tried to setup the network manually without success. route also looks ok.

Any ideas what could have happend?

Comment: This bug looks very similar: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/921123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one solved my problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/76557/34563